# How to make human readable yaml files with PyYaml

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I'm using python to load another python file and add it to a yaml file. The problem I'm running into is that the resulting yaml file has the entire contents of the python file represented as a single string with newlines replaced as `\n`.

My code is as follows:

```py
import yaml

with open("yaml_file.yaml", "r") as doc1_content:
    doc1_content = doc1_content.read()

with open("python_file.py", "r") as python_fh:
    python_content = python_fh.read()

doc1_content = yaml.safe_load(doc1_content)
doc1_content['key'] = python_content

with open("output_yaml.yaml", "w") as generated_yaml:
    yaml.dump(doc1_content, generated_yaml, default_flow_style=False, default_style=None)
```

It seems that assigning `python_content` to the dict performs the conversion.

So the question is,

1. Is it possible to prevent the conversion when assigning to the dict? or...
2. Is it possible to have Pyyaml's `yaml.dump()` convert the string to a multiline string with `\n`'s replaced?

EDIT: After some more testing, it seems to only happen once the python file I'm inserting exceeds 455 bytes.

Example intput:

```py
import boto3
import json
import re
from datetime import datetime
from distutils.util import strtobool


config_client = boto3.client('config')
elb_client = boto3.client('elb')
elbv2_client = boto3.client('elbv2')
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

sns_client = boto3.client('sns')


account_id = sts_client.get_caller_identity().get('Account')
region = sts_client.meta.region_name


def fetch_all_items(method, response_key, next_token_key, **kwargs):
 if
```

Output:

```yaml
key: "import boto3\nimport json\nimport re\nfrom datetime import datetime\nfrom distutils.util\
  \ import strtobool\n\n\nconfig_client = boto3.client('config')\nelb_client = boto3.client('elb')\n\
  elbv2_client = boto3.client('elbv2')\nsts_client = boto3.client('sts')\n\nsns_client\
  \ = boto3.client('sns')\n\n\naccount_id = sts_client.get_caller_identity().get('Account')\n\
  region = sts_client.meta.region_name\n\n\ndef fetch_all_items(method, response_key,\
  \ next_token_key, **kwargs):\n if\n"
somekey: somevalue
```

Comment: The code does what you say it does - there is no conversion involved. ssm_doc_path is referencing the yaml file which you are using safe_load to convert into a dict.
ssm_python_path is read as a block of text and is assigned to the "key" key in the loaded yaml before you dump it out.
Do you intend both files to be yaml files that you want to merge?

Comment: @PaulWhipp I updated the question to provide clarifying info. It seems to only happen once the python file reaches a certain size.